# USA made handheld

Tags: ht

I am looking for advice on new to HAM studies.
I have a pair of FRS Motorola T800 walkie talkies and an old pair of REalistic TRC-215 6 channel, 5W, CB handhelds.

As I read, and ask questions, a friend suggested Baufeng units. They are made in China and seem less than quality?

Thanks,

Gerry

Comment: Hi, [this similar question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/radio-manufactured-in-united-states) has some useful answers.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: I came *this* close to closing this as a shopping question, but it might be a duplicate instead? As well?